# Compare two records

Tags: crystal-reports

My report needs to compare order quotations, grouped by a sales part number.  These order quotations generally have mostly the same sales parts within them, but occasionally they differ.  I need:

- Quote 1 (Q1) - Total sales = Q1 sales qty * Q1 bid price
- Quote 2 (Q1) - Total sales = Q2 sales qty * Q2 bid price
- Desired info - Total sales = Q2 sales qty * Q1 bid price (If sales part does not exist on Q2, then - Desired info - Total sales = Q1 sales qty * Q1 bid price)

I'm pulling data from a simple SQL query and using the two quote numbers as parameters. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Couldn't understand exactly where you are struck.... are you looking for some logical conditon?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to come up with the logical condition within Crystal to accomplish the objective for this report.  Any help is appreciated.